# Writing to CSV issue

Tags: python

I've done this 100 times, but for some reason I can't get this to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
csv_file = open('test_a.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
writer.writerow('test')
```

OR

```
csv_file = open('test_a.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
writer.writerows(['test'])
```

OR

```
csv_file = open('test_a.csv', 'a')
writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
writer.writerow('test')
```

The CSV file is created, but nothing gets written.

Comment: do you get an error message or unexpected output?

Comment: updated my question

Comment: Unrelated but why are you opening the file in binary mode? Also, has the program finished when you inspect the file or is this some ongoing loop?

Comment: What would be an alternate way of opening it? I'm opening the file, scraping some data off websites and writing rows to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call a `.close()` on the file object or open `with` a context manager:

```
with open('test_a.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow(['test'])
```

Comment: What is the difference between using "with" and not using it?

Comment: Saves you the burden of calling `csv_file.close()`. Python does the closing and cleanup for you once the `with` context has expired.

Answer (score -1):

The `writerow` method expects a list of values.  You're giving it a string, which is iterable.. so you end up with `t, e, s, t` which is probably not what you want.  Make sure you are passing a list:

```
writer.writerow(['test'])
```

Comment: unfortunately nothing is being written to the CSV file and I don't understand why

Comment: I ran your code and it worked other than this issue.  However, I did close the file afterward.  Are you closing the file?